# What is the IPP message to be POSTed to a printer in order to get its attributes and more?

Tags: printing, tcp, protocols, printers

I'm working on `stm32` and trying to get a printer attributes through TCP, I'm reading the IPP documentation and get to find the right message to send

A client TCP socket is created and is connected to port 631 of my printer address
Then a send a message with the Ipp header and I get a response from everything but an HP printer but the response is not as expected according to IPP documentation

In C I send

```
    /ipp HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/ipp\r\n
    User-Agent: Internet Printing Provider\r\n
    Host: 10.34.18.44:631\r\nContent-Length: 117\r\n
    Connection: Keep-Alive\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n
    \001\001\0\v\0\0\0\v
    \001G\0\022attributes-charset\0\005utf-8H\0
    \eattributes-natural-language\0\005en-usE\0
    \vprinter-uri\0\032http://10.34.18.44:631/ipp\003\020
```

In C# I send

```
    string _uri = "10.34.18.44";
    string printeruriValue = _uri + ":631/ipp";
    string content = $"{0x0101}";
    content += $"{0x000A}";
    content += $"{0x00000123}";
    content += $"{0x01}"; 
    content += $"{0x47}{0x0012}attributes-charset{0x0005}utf-8";
    content += $"{0x48}{0x001B}attributes-natural-language{0x0005}en-us";
    content += $"{0x45}{0x000B}printer-uri{0x001A}{printeruriValue}";
    content += $"{0x21}{0x0005}limit{0x0004}{0x00000032}";
    content += $"{0x44}{0x0014}requested-attributes{0x0006}job-id";
    content += $"{0x44}{0x0000}{0x0008}job-name";
    content += $"{0x44}{0x0000}{0x000F}document-format";
    content += $"{0x0003}";

    string message = $"POST {_uri + "/ipp"}  HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/ipp\r\n" +
    "User-Agent: Internet Printing Provider\r\n" +
    "Host:" + _uri + ":631\r\n" +
    $"Content-Length: {content.Length}\r\n"+
    "Connection: Keep - Alive\r\n" +
    "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n"+
    content;
```

And every time I receive from a not HP printer

```
    ReceiveCallback close : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Server: JC-SHTTPD/1.17.23
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: application/ipp
    Content-Length: 33
    Accept-Ranges: none

    ????G?attributes-charset??
```

and from an HP printer a 405 error, command unknown

Comment: Is this a C problem or a problem of sending the right string? What does your C# code do?

Comment: I tried in C# because I use a embedded device and in C# it s easier to test, It s not a C problem ( I may have an issue with my cp1252 eclipse format) but a misunderstanding about what I need to send to communicate with the printer

Comment: in fact G returned is the ascii value of one of the parameter , it looks like it send only the first attribute, furthermore some printer with IPP actived don't seem to recognize my call and I end with 400 bad request error

Comment: @manulateigne How did you resolved this issue.

Comment: I went into using ipp tool via ubuntu then i catched with wire shark the message being sent and their response. The trick is the order of argument and i noticed that some printer needs / command or /ipp command, hence i try both until i got a correct answer